# Here is my code for the calculation of BMI with inputs and operations is the following correct in terms of structure and formulas?

Tags: python

```
#input
name = input("Enter your name:")
height = input ("Height:")
weight = input ("Weight:")
print("Weight:" + weight +"kg")
print("height:" + height +"m")
print("My name is " + name +"!")

#operations with decimal numbers
metres = float(height)
height_sqr =  pow(metres,2)

kg = float(weight)
BMI = float(kg)/height_sqr

#print BMI results
print("BMI:" +str(BMI) +"Kg/M2")
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Comment: Thanks I just learned from a tutorial video could there be a shorter more efficient one?

Comment: I have answered  an efficient and better algorithm for calculating BMI below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a more optimized method here it is :

```
# getting input from the user and assigning it to the user

height = float(input("Enter height in meters: "))
weight = float(input("Enter weight in kg: "))

# the formula for calculating bmi

bmi = weight/(height**2) 
# ** is the power of operator i.e height*height in this case

print("Your BMI is: {0} and you are: ".format(bmi), end='')

#conditions
if ( bmi < 16):
   print("severely underweight")

elif ( bmi >= 16 and bmi < 18.5):
   print("underweight")

elif ( bmi >= 18.5 and bmi < 25):
   print("Healthy")

elif ( bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30):
   print("overweight")

elif ( bmi >=30):
   print("severely overweight")
```

Here you neither have to take input as a string and then convert it into a float nor you have to use a function to calculate power.
It also shows the range in which your BMI lies.

Well, the efficiency of the code will be the same.

Comment: thanks vishwampandya I have always thought its "else if"

Comment: @ZenChen - If you think that my answer is satisfactory can you mark it as the correct answer. It would help me too. Thanks